Proof of continuity for a generalized form of the Dirchlet function?
Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined by:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
        f_1(x) & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
        f_2(x) & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q}^c
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Show that $f$ is continuous at $x = x_0$ if and only if $f_1(x_0) = f_2(x_0)$.
Here is how I tried the $\implies$ case:
Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.
$\implies | \ f(x) \ - \ f(x_0) \ | < \epsilon \ \ \forall \ x \in (x-c,x+c) $
Case 1: $x_0 \in \mathbb{Q}$
First, we ensure the continuity of $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ in the $\delta$-neighborhood of $x_0$:
$ | \ f(x) - f_1(x) \ | < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \ \forall \ x \in (x_0-c,x_0+c) \ \text{such that} \ x \in \mathbb{Q} $
Next, we ensure the continuity of $x \in \mathbb{Q}^c$ in the $\delta$-neighborhood of $x_0$:
$ | \ f(x) - f_2(x) \ | < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \ \forall \ x \in (x_0-c,x_0+c) \ \text{such that} \ x \in \mathbb{Q}^c $
Combining the two conditions, we obtain:
\begin{align*}
| \ f_1(x) - f_2(x) \ | &= | \ f_1(x) -f(x) + f(x) - f_2(x) \ | \\
&\leq | \ f_1(x) - f(x)  \ | + | \ f(x) - f_2(x) \ | \\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
&= \epsilon
\end{align*}
Since $\epsilon$ can be made arbitrarily small, we get:
$$ f_1(x_0) = f_2(x_0) $$
Case 2: $x_0 \in \mathbb{Q}^c$
The proof for Case 2 is similar to Case 1.
Is the proof so far valid, and how would I go about proving the  other part?

Is there anything specific you think may not be correct in the proof or any specific points where you are confused about proving the other part?

What are $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$? Are they both continuous functions?
